# Force Maven to resolve dependecy only from acivated profile repo else throw error

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have same repository hosted at multiple remote places. Is there any way to say maven to use only the repo defined in the profile or throw the error. don't fall back to the central (defined in pom.xml), or settle with locally downloaded artifact.

Here is pom.xml

```
   <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <id>central</id>
                        <url>https://central.maven.repo/repository</url>
                        <releases>
                            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        </snapshots>
                    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Here is my setting.xml containing profiles

```
<settings>
    ...
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile1</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>profile1-repo</id>
                    <url>https://maven.repository-of-profile1/repository</url>
                    <releases>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>profile2</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>profile2-repo</id>
                    <url>https://maven.repository-of-profile2/repository</url>
                    <releases>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>central</id>
            <username>central_username</username>
            <password>central_password</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>profile1-repo</id>
        <server>
            <id>profile2-repo</id>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Here is how I am running the command

```
mvn -f pom.xml -s settings.xml  -P profile1 dependency:get -DgroupId=... -DartifactId=... -Dversion=1.2.3-SNAPSHOT
```

but it just gives warning if the artifact is not available from **profile1** and fallback to the **central**. My main objective it to check the availability at all the places.

Comment: Could you explain why you want this? What is the problem if Maven just checks all the repositories until it finds something? Why omit central?

Comment: @JFabianMeier Because I just wanted to check the connectivity/reachability to the desired repo at different location always.

Comment: What is the point of having the same dependency in different repositories?

Comment: High availability

Comment: Providing high availability by using different URLs is not how it is done. Instead, you put several instances of an Artifactory or Nexus behind the **same** URL.

Comment: And BTW, if your dependency is in MavenCentral, you do not need to worry about availability.

Comment: no, its not in maven central, its in private repo. In the actual use case, there are two instances of an application suite running at different location and maven is one part of it

Answer (score 0):

You may block maven central repository in settings.xml via specifying mirror, for example:

```xml
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>blocked-central</id>
            <name>blocked maven central</name>
            <url>https://0.0.0.0</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <blocked>true</blocked>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

Comment: Will it not cause any problem while resolving dependencies for actual pom.xml, which contain central repositories; when no additional profiles  are specified?